# How to show popover only in window bounds?

Tags: macos, nspopover

Button which show the popover lay on the button left corner of window.
How to show popover only in window bounds?
Attention! Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. NSPopover is a floating window that is connected to a certain other window but otherwise stays completely on its own. You can however try manually to keep it within certain bounds on screen by calculating a popup position that keeps the popover bounds with that area. But this won't work in all cases anyway (e.g. if the user moves the app window so that there's simply not enough room for the popover).